# ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuted prefixes properties in json body with underscore

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

In my Web Api project i am trying to separate the business logic in separate modules that could be potentially used in other applications (such as a WCF service).

For this reason, in order to create a common way of giving exceptions i have created a class that inherits from exception and there i am passing an object containing my business errors.

So the application should handle the exceptions thrown from the business layer.

In this specific case i have created a Filter that i have made global, so all controllers' actions have this filter. The filter code is:

```
Public Class MyCustomActionFilterAttribute
    Inherits System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute

    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(actionContext As Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext)
        If Not actionContext.ModelState.IsValid Then

            Dim Errors As New List(Of ErrorResult)

            For Each lError In actionContext.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(Function(x) x.Errors) 
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lError.ErrorMessage) Then
                    Errors.Add(New ErrorResult(lError.ErrorMessage))
                Else
                    Errors.Add(New ErrorResult With {.Code = ErrorCode.GenericValidationError, .Description = lError.Exception.Message})
                End If
            Next

            actionContext.Response = New HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) With {
               .Content = New ObjectContent(Of List(Of ErrorResult)) _
                   (Errors, New System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter)
           }
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext As Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext)
        MyBase.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext)
        If Not actionExecutedContext.Exception Is Nothing Then
            Dim Errors As New List(Of ErrorResult)
            If actionExecutedContext.Exception.GetType Is GetType(MyCustomException) Then
                Errors.Add(CType(actionExecutedContext.Exception, MyCustomException).ErrorResult)
            Else
                Errors.Add(New ErrorResult With {.Code = ErrorCode.GenericError, .Description = actionExecutedContext.Exception.Message})
            End If
            actionExecutedContext.Response = New HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) With {
               .Content = New ObjectContent(Of List(Of ErrorResult)) _
                   (Errors, New System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter)
           }
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

With the above i want to achieve a common way of presenting the exceptions. So i have a class `ErrorResult` which just have two properties `Code` and `Description`.

When i have an issue with the ModelState i do get a nice json array as the following:

```
[{Code: -1001, Description: "Error Description"}]
```

Which is what i want to see. This is created by the `OnActionExecuting` method.

My problem is that when an error exists in the `OnActionExecuted` method, the response i get is :

```
[{_Code: -1001, _Description: "Error Description"}]
```

Why do i get these underscores and how can i possibly get rid of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that not knowing when the problem lies, leads you to ask the wrong question. Of course if you knew the right question, then probably you would know the answer.

In my case the problem was not in the `OnActionExecuted` method, but the way json is serialized when you decorate your classes with the `Serializable` attribute.

In the code posted in my question `MyCustomException` class is decorated as `Serializable` and it seems that the JsonMediaTypeFormatter behaves that way ([asp-net-web-api-is-serializing-with-underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739732/asp-net-web-api-is-serializing-with-underscore)).

So all i had to do was to define the Json.Net `DefaultContractResolver` :

```
actionExecutedContext.Response = New HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) With {
    .Content = New ObjectContent(Of List(Of ErrorResult)) _
        (Errors, New System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter With
    {
        .SerializerSettings = New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings With
        {
            .NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            .ContractResolver = New DefaultContractResolver
        }
    })
}
```